# How to fix Laravel Blade, Vuejs and Handlebars.js delimiter (mustache) issue?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, handlebars.js

Handlebars.js file that done not load if it is placed VueJs container (#app).

```js
<script id="details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="label label-info"> @{{ domain }}'s Email</div>
</script>
```

I get the error message raised by Vue.

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "domain" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

When I remove the #app id from the container, handlebar template works fine. I have tried to change the VueJs delimiter in app.js file

```vue
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app', 
   delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
});
```

It did not work.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `domain` variable is not defined and you are trying to use it in your HTML. You should initialize the variable and then use it. try this:

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app', 
   delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
   domain: null
});
```

Comment: I am passing the 'domain' from Jquery to the template.